# Speeding up ST_Value in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, performance, extract

I am working on a large point file and am looking to get the raster value underneath each point. I am using:

```
UPDATE Locations a SET image3b3_sum = ST_Value(rast, 1, geom)
FROM image_sum_sum;
```

10 records takes 31 seconds and 1,000 takes 5:24 minutes. As I add more points 
 I am noticing a linear trend on how long this will take, and for 1,000,000 points this will get nuts.

I have tried tiling the raster however it results in NULL values being assigned. What can I do to speed this up? I have looked at:
[How to speed up queries for raster databases?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43053/how-to-speed-up-queries-for-raster-databases) but, as I mentioned, tiling causes null values to occur:

```
NOTICE:  Attempting to get pixel value with out of range raster coordinates: (-2638, -2441)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function st_value(raster,integer,geometry,boolean) line 18 at RETURN
```

The raster and point file have indexes. Are there constraints I can add to the raster to make it go faster?

UPDATE_1:

I have tried adding in an ST_Intersects as suggested but still yielding NULL values and long times to process:

```
UPDATE Locations a SET image3b3_sum = ST_Value(ST_Tile(rast,1,100,100), 1, geom)
FROM image_sum_sum b
WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.rast);
```

Comment: Null values still persist as before. It is like it is loading all points and testing each against each tile. Would a FOR loop with RID as the agent and ST_Envelope of each tile be a solution?

Comment: Taking the Tile out of the query and using the ST_Intersects resulted in 19s for 100,000 records with no NULL values!! Please put that as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import the raster with `raster2pgsql` using the `-t TILE_SIZE` as suggested in djq's answer to [How to speed up queries for raster databases?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43053/how-to-speed-up-queries-for-raster-databases/43680#43680), instead of tiling it on the fly with `ST_Tile` (for memory efficiency). Every tile will be inserted in a row in the raster table (`image_sum_sum`).

Then, as suggested in apricity's answer to [Only select non null values using st_value on Postgis tiled raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/212517/only-select-non-null-values-using-st-value-on-postgis-tiled-raster/212519#212519), use the `ST_Intersects` in the `WHERE` clause to take advantage from the gist index in the geometry table (`locations`).

```
UPDATE locations a SET image3b3_sum = ST_Value(b.rast, 1, a.geom)
FROM image_sum_sum b
WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.rast);
```